# How should I persist a session token between controllers in iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm building an iOS application which fetches all of it's data from an online API.

The API requires that the user is validated before other resources may be accessed and each subsequent request must send a valid session ID.

What's the best way to persist the session ID from controller to controller?

Set it as a global somewhere? Save it as an entity? Or pass it as an attribute from controller to controller at each segue?

Advice appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the token in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) rather than injecting as a property or ivar on every controller. I'd also extract it from defaults in the object or shared instance that handles your web service/ API interactions (rather than have every controller look it up).

PS: If you want secure storage, use the [Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).